# showing rdlc reporting tab in visual studio 2017

Tags: asp.net, rdlc, visual-studio-2017

I am attempting view report using asp.net webform in visual studio.
I install VS 2017 and Microsoft Rdlc Report Designer for Visual Studio-Sql Reporting Services.

But now i cannot find Reporting tab in toolbox.I tried but i can not solve this.There is not many resource about VS2017.

Can any one resolve this.Any kind of help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to install the Rdlc Report Designer for Visual Studio 2017. Download here:

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SqlReportingServices.MicrosoftRdlcReportDesignerforVisualStudio-18001